# How to remove apostrophe s in sql in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, special-characters

im still learning SQL for Big Query . How do i remove the "apostrophe s"
in this word  **Let*'s* Go** ? I do need to so some cleaning in the list of data for a single column .
Thanks

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#replace `REPLACE("Let's Go", "'s", "s")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below

```
select replace("Let's Go", "'", "")
```

with output

[image]